# Cannot Consume Json message using Kafka connect json api

Tags: java, apache-kafka

my code to consume kafka, it is not printing any output

I am trying to consume json message through kafka but not giving any input, 
here is my Input: {"opp_id":"2","opp_tenant_id":"3","createdWhen":"4"}
I am able to receive as string deserializer but not using Jsondeserializer

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

KafkaConsumer<String, JsonNode> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, JsonNode>(props);
    try {
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode> records = consumer.poll(100); 
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, JsonNode> record : records) {               
            JsonNode jsonNode = record.value();
       System.out.println(mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode,Contact.class));
        }
            }
    }
```

Pojo,

```
public class Contact {
    private String opp_id;
    private String opp_tenant_id;
    private String createdWhen;

public Contact(String opp_id,String opp_tenant_id, String createdWhen)
{
    this.opp_id =opp_id;
    this.opp_tenant_id = opp_tenant_id;
    this.createdWhen = createdWhen;

}

public void parseString(String csvStr){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(csvStr,",");
    opp_id = st.nextToken();
    opp_tenant_id = st.nextToken();
    createdWhen = st.nextToken();
}

public Contact() {}

public String getopp_id(){
    return opp_id;
}
public Contact setopp_id(String opp_id) {
    this.opp_id=opp_id;
    return this;
}
public String getopp_tenant_id(){
    return opp_tenant_id;
}
public Contact setopp_tenant_id(String opp_tenant_id) {
    this.opp_tenant_id=opp_tenant_id;
    return this;
}

public String getcreatedWhen(){
    return createdWhen;
}
public Contact setcreatedWhen(String createdWhen) {
    this.createdWhen=createdWhen;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: what do you want? you want to convert JSON into POJO? then override `toString()` method in `Contact` class and `System.out.println(mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode,Contact.class).toString()); @user

Comment: @user-Deadpool I want to consume Json message and print it out. this is my input {"opp_id":"1","opp_tenant_id":"2","createdWhen":"3"} through producer. the cosumer is not printing any result when I give input. even tried System.out.println(mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode,Contact.class).toString()) not printing any result.

Comment: okay did you check that your input was published to kafka? how are you inserting this input into kafka? by producer? @Chethan

Comment: you can check by using `kafka tool` @Chethan

Comment: @Deadpool yes my input is getting published to kafka, I verified using this /kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server local:9092  --topic . I tried to give input manually through producer and also through JSon serializer     Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.parseString(line);
            JsonNode  jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(contact);
            ProducerRecord<String, JsonNode> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, JsonNode>(topicName,jsonNode);

Comment: can you post your properties for consumer @Chethan

Comment: consumer properties  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
     props.put("group.id", "test");     props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
     props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer");

Comment: you are missing topic name @Chethan

Comment: @Deadpool code is not failing, code is running without any errors, but not consuming any messages. consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topicname"));
 when I tried using these props it is printing the results      //props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     //props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"); but not with jsondeserializer

Comment: okay to make it clear you want to consume JSON message and print in JSON format. am i right?

Comment: @Deadpool yes correct, I want to confirm it is consuming the Json format message by printing it for now. so that I can use in further process.

Comment: are you using apache kafka?

Comment: so from the documentation in apache kafka there is no JSON Deserializer, apache kafka provides only StringDeserializer, for more information https://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/package-tree.html

Comment: @Deadpool yes I am using apache-kafka, and for jsondeserializer I am using connect-json-1.1.1.jar this jar.

Comment: i don't think so this is good approach and this is going to workout, still with StringDeserializer you are able to read JSON and convert into JAVA POJO class (it's working like charm) so if you want to use JSON Deserializer i prefer using Spring kafka

Comment: thanks @Deadpool for the idea, let me try converting reading JSon as string and convert to POJO.

Comment: let me know still if you have issues? @user

Comment: @Deadpool, your solution worked for me. and I ran into another issue. Any thoughts will be helpful. I am new to kafka. I am losing messages produced between stop and start. for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622285/messages-lost-between-apache-kafka-consumer-stop-and-start

Comment: sorry i thought it not worked

Comment: oh okay i got you, here consumer is identified by `groupid` so once consumer is attached to kafka it will submit offset which means it will not consume messages that already consumed by that consumer group, to get more idea read docs here https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache kafka does not have any `JsonDeserializer` and all deserialize classes available in apache kafka are `ByteArrayDeserializer, IntegerDeserializer, LongDeserializer, StringDeserializer` (for more information [here](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html) ) so you can use `StringDeserializer` to read the message in String JSON format and use `Object mapper` to convert JSON String to POJO class
or if you want to use `JsonDeserializer` prefer Spring kafka